# Javascript: AppendChild appends twice instead of one

Tags: javascript, appendchild

This is my code:

```
this.renderHtml = function () {
    var html = '';
    var domElementId = this.jqElementId;
    html += '<div id = "'+domElementId+'" class="widget-content widget-wrapper" style="background-color:#eee; height: 100px; width: 400px">'+
                '<div class="container">'+
                    '<div class="rulerContainer"></div>'+
                    '<div class="progressBarContainer" style="background-color:#ccffdd; height: 15px"></div>'+
                    '<div class="displayValue" style="background-color: #e6ffff; height: 15px color: red"></div>'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>';
    return html;
}; 

this.afterRender = function () {
    this.widgetLogic(this.properties.Value);
};

this.updateProperty = function (updatePropertyInfo) {
    if (updatePropertyInfo.TargetProperty === 'Value') {
        this.setProperty('Value', updatePropertyInfo.SinglePropertyValue);
        this.widgetLogic(updatePropertyInfo.SinglePropertyValue);
    }
};

this.widgetLogic = function(rawValue) {
    var value = (rawValue === undefined ? 0 : parseInt(rawValue));
    var name = this.jqElementId;
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("displayValue")[0].innerHTML = value;
    var rulerContainer = document.createElement('div');
    rulerContainer.className = "marker";
    document.getElementsByClassName("rulerContainer")[0].appendChild(rulerContainer);
    $('.marker').css('width','20px');
    $('.marker').css('height','50px');
    $('.marker').css('border-right','1px solid green');
};
```

According to this code I'm supposed to see a green vertical line inside rulercontainer class.
My result is I see **two** lines instead of one and I don't understand why

[image]

Comment: How are `afterRender` and `updateProperty` being called??

Comment: Put some console.log() inside `this.widgetLogic = function(rawValue)` and test if is it called twice.

Comment: @RaV I've just checked and, yes, it is called twice but I don't understand why.
Plus I've seen that if I take the two div ProgressBar and displayValue off it works.
I put the console.log inside each function and this is the result
`renderHtml
afterRender
widgetLogic
updateProperty
widgetLogic
updateProperty`
So it looks like it calls twice widgetLogic and UpdateProperty

Comment: `this.widgetLogic(updatePropertyInfo.SinglePropertyValue);` - I guess its this one which call it second time.

Comment: You just need to revise your conditions. Maybe add some variable, I dont see whole code, so I cant really tell `if (updatePropertyInfo.TargetProperty === 'Value')`.

Comment: @RaV Ok, it may be... the problem is that I need the function to be there because it update my value.
But who calls updateProperty for the second time?

Comment: Your code doesn't show that part :P probably.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I don't know that part either.
I just know I must insert a code with (at least) the function renderHtml, afterRender and updateProperty (other functions are up to me) and then the platform calls those functions. 
What I showed to you is all I wrote and all I know